# Trying to scrape from mutiple pages with same link

Tags: python, selenium

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver.exe')
url ='https://www.sambav.com/hyderabad/doctors'

driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

for links in soup.find_all('div',class_='sambavdoctorname'):
    link = links.find('a')
    print(link['href'])

driver.close()
```

I am trying to scrape this page, the link is same in all pages. I am trying to extract the links from all mutiple pages but it's not giving any output nor showing any error just the program gets end.

Answer (score 0):

If you check that website by developer tools in browser ( chrome or mozilla or whatever), before loading website, the website fetch data from few sources. One of this sources is "https://www.sambav.com/api/search/DoctorSearch?searchText=&city=Hyderabad&location=" . Your code could be simplified (and there is no need to use selenium):

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.sambav.com/api/search/DoctorSearch?searchText=&city=Hyderabad&location=') 
BASE_URL_DOCTOR = 'https://www.sambav.com/hyderabad/doctor/'
for item in r.json():
    print(BASE_URL_DOCTOR + item['uniqueName'])
```